# Query regarding $L^{2}$ functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, mathematical-physics, fourier-transform

Given that a wave-function $\psi$ can be written as the superposition of plane waves where $\mathbf k$ is the wave vector (3D) and $g({\mathbf k})$ is a complex fn, must be sufficiently regular to allow differentiation inside the integral.

Now, the author states that,

> any square-integrable function can be written in the following form

Now, I don't understand how to show that the statement is true, that is, assuming that $\psi \ \epsilon \ \mathcal{L}^{2}[\mathbb{R}^3]$.
Show that,

$$\psi({{\mathbf r},t})= \frac {1}{(2{\pi})^\frac{3}{2}} \int  {\rm d}^3{\bf k}\; g({\mathbf k}) e^{i({\mathbf{k}\cdot{\bf r}} - {\omega ({\mathbf k})}t)}$$

References:

1. "Quantum Mechanics - Cohen Tannoudji" Pg. 22 Eqn (C-6)

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: The statement is too vague. What do you mean by superposition of plane waves? Already the formula you wrote may be false for $t=0$ (the superposition above) because the integral, taken literally,  may diverge if $\psi$ is $L^2$. Personally, I do not like this false rigour...I refer to the book. It would be better a formal use of symbols accompanied by physical sense.

Comment: My deep apologies, I have edited the part where the author describes the function $g(\mathbf k)$ to be fairly regular and differentiable under the integral sign. Now, given this, I assume that the integral doesn't diverge even when $t=0$, right?

Comment: No apologies :) What I mean is that the decomposition in plane waves for $L^2$ functions is performed in terms of a map that is not an integral (see @mike stone's answer). It is the Plancherel transform and not the Fourier integral. In this sense all the issue relies on false mathematical rigour...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fourier transform is a *unitary map* $L^2[{\mathbb R}^n]\to L^2[{\mathbb R}^n]$, although the integrals involved are not  necessarily proper, and limits may have to be taken in the $L^2[{\mathbb R}^n]$ sense. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#On_L2) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem).

A longer, less rigorous, but perhaps more accessible account can be found in chapter 2 of my  book with Paul Goldbart, a draft copy of which can be found [here](https://goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf)

Comment: Perhaps you could expand on the details, I am assuming the OP has not taken any course on formal functional analysis, so this answer must be complemented with accessible explanations, namely make the Wiki explanation useful for the level. I believe the interesting part is showing that the integral written makes sense (converges) since the original function is square integrable not necessarily in $\mathcal{L}^1$.

Comment: The OP asks "show that" and it is not possible to give a proof without a full course on functional analysis. In particlular one needs to understand some form  proof of the completeness on $L^2$ spaces. Usually in physics we accept Parseval's theorem for Fourier *series*  and then trust that replacing the sum by an integral is a harmless extension. Ill add a link to our lecture notes that is the best I can do for a physical motivation.

Comment: So the naive way to prove the convergence of the integral you wrote is to bound its factors by their "sup" (or maximum value), however one would have to formally make an Ansatz for the function $g$ (namely define it as the fourier transform of $\psi$) and then attempt to find bounds for it. All these are generally details of mathematical physics and may or may not be important (depending on your interests). You can find much formal details on the links supplied in the answer.